# DRV8711 Stall detection issue

Tags: driver, stepper-motor, texas-instruments, back-emf

I've got a [`BOOST-DRV8711` dev board](http://www.ti.com/tool/boost-drv8711)  to have some fun with the `DRV8711` IC.

I'm interested in stall detection, to detect when the motor loses steps.
Using a general purpose MCU I wired the SPI and the `STEP`/`DIR` pins. I'm able to read/write the internal registers and to move the motor.

To try this feature I set these parameters:

- torque = 128, smplth = 200 us
- microstepping = 1/16
- sdthr = 0xFF, sdcnt = 1 step, vdiv = / 32

All other settings are left on their default value.
[This is the motor I'm using (with no load.](http://www.applied-motion.com/sites/default/files/HT17-268_RevC.pdf)

I set the motor to run @ 1000 step/s and I clamped the axis, but nothing happened (I was expecting the stall LED turns on.)
Because the stall condition is met when the BEMF drops below the sdthr value I reduced both torque and speed settings - with no luck.

I'm using the most sensitive settings to detect a stall condition (maximum value for sdthr and lowest value for vdiv). Running the motor at a very low speed (down to 10 step/s) I bet I should detect a "stall".

Perhaps I misunderstood the datasheet.

Comment: When you say you *"clamped the axis"* do you mean you stopped it moving completely? The datasheet, section 7.3.10.1 Internal Stall Detection says *"This stall detection scheme is only effective when the motor is stalled while running at or above some minimum speed. Because it relies on detecting a drop in motor back EMF, the motor must be rotating with sufficient speed to generate a detectable back EMF. During motor start-up, and at very slow step rates, the stall detection is not reliable."*

Comment: Yes it's exacly what I did - unless I still don't understand. I apologize, English is not my primary language. While the motor was still rotating at 1000 step/s I "clamped the axis", i.e. the axis has stopped, but the step pin was still pulsing. I think this is the correct situation: the motor WAS above some minimum speed when it actually stalled.

Comment: Maybe it also needs to maintain some minimum speed *after* stalling, otherwise there will be no back EMF to detect. Try running it faster then just clamp lightly so it misses steps and runs a bit slower.

Comment: I will try. But in that case I cannot use this feature as a "poor man's end switch".

Comment: If you need limit switches, add limit switches. Fix the problem in the right place.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's not uncommon for some applications with light loads to detect the end of the rail when the motor stalls. Perhaps it's not the best way but it's effective! Anyway, I don't see any evidence of the fact DRV8711 cannot detect such a stall. I'm going to ask to TI, and report back any answer.

Comment: Ok, good luck! Just bear in mind that they may quote that section of the datasheet back at you and say that you're not running fast enough for the stall detection to be reliable. In such a case, I personally would be very cautious about trusting it until you have done more testing.

Comment: Thanks for the hints! Anyway I've just tried at 6000 step/s and I can't see any stall indication. I need to dig it further.

Comment: Ok, maybe try other values for that SDTHR register too, it wasn't completely clear to me whether 0xFF is more sensitive than the default 0x40 or less sensitive. It does say that the correct settings "must be found by experimentation", which is what you're doing.

Comment: @RogerRowland you are misunderstanding the stall feature and the datasheet.  The motor does not need to be moving to detect a stall.  Stalling means the motor stopped.  It must be moving at a sufficient speed initially but any stall normally stops the motor.  It is very difficult for a stepper motor to continue moving when it has missed a step or two at speed.

Comment: @jcoffland Yes, if you're referring to my guess about needing a minimum speed *after* stalling, I agree that's wrong (but I was just shooting in the dark). I think we both agree that it's likely to be the too-slow initial speed that is/was the OP's original problem. It would be nice to have an update if it's resolved now because it may help future readers.

Comment: Yes, I solved, but unfortunately the issue wasn't directly related to the stall detector behavior I described. There was a problem on the SPI communication and for some reasons some registers weren't properly set. Fixed that, after some experimentations (as we all know!) I got the stall detector to work!